# Defining equivalence of equivalences without assuming extensionality

Tags: homotopy-type-theory

In homotopy type theory, we say that a function $f$ is an equivalence between two types $A$ and $B$, if the inverse image of all points is contractible (as per say the [n-lab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/equivalence+in+homotopy+type+theory) or Paolo's Capriotti's [Agda formalization](http://www.paolocapriotti.com/agda-base/trunc/hott.equivalence.core.html#1)).  The "problem" with this definition is that if $A$ is a function type, the resulting definition asks for (propositional) equality of functions.

Equivalently, one could proceed as per section 2.4 of the [HoTT book](http://homotopytypetheory.org/book/) and define equivalence via quasi-inverse (which is the route we've chosen).

But this makes no actual difference: while one can ask if two equivalences are equivalent, the unwinding of the definitions still ends up asking if two functions are equal.

More precisely, question #1 is: given two equivalences $eq_1,\ eq_2 : A \simeq B$, how do I define a concept $eq_1 \approxeq eq_2$ that properly expresses that $eq_1$ and $eq_1$ are equivalent equivalences without resorting to extensionality?

One of my attempts (in Agda), reads as follows:

```
record _≋′_ {ℓ ℓ' : Level} {A : Set ℓ} {B : Set ℓ'} (eq₁ eq₂ : A ≃ B) : Set (ℓ ⊔ ℓ') where
constructor eq′
field
  pA : A ≃ A -- automorphism of A
  pB : B ≃ B -- automorphism of B
  f≡ : ∀ x → eq₁ ⋆ x P.≡ (pB ● (eq₂ ● pA)) ⋆ x
  g≡ : ∀ x → (sym≃ eq₁) ⋆ x P.≡ (pA ● (sym≃ eq₂ ● pB)) ⋆ x
```

where $\star$ is often called happly, and ● is composition of equivalences.  But I must admit that this somehow doesn't feel quite right (even though it works perfectly well for my application).

Question #2: is there a unique definition of *equivalence* which would properly unify these?  [I suspect that such a definition may end up having to be indexed by h-level].

Comment: What do you mean "quasi-inverses as per section 2.4"? The type of quasi-inverses (2.4.5) is *not* equivalent to the type of equivalences (2.4.11) and should not be used as a substitute.

Comment: You might be interested in Mike Shulman's blog post "Universal properties without function extensionality" (http://homotopytypetheory.org/2014/11/02/universal-properties-without-function-extensionality/)

Comment: @AndrejBauer: I was working with quasi-inverses, but you are right, I should work with proper equivalences instead.

Comment: @JasonGross: I had read it, but forgot that it was topical.  Thanks for the reminder, I am re-reading it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equivalences $e_1, e_2 : A \simeq B$ are elements of the type $A \simeq B$. Recall from the HoTT book (2.4.11) that $A \simeq B$ is defined as $\sum_{f : A \to B} \mathsf{isequiv}(f)$. The easiest way to compare elements is of course just (propostional) equality. Because $\mathsf{isprop}(f)$ is a proposition, $e_1 = e_2$ reduces to $f_1 = f_2$, as you note. Without function extensionality it is typically quite hard to prove equality of functions, so you could weaken the condition to $f_1$ and $f_2$ being homotopic: $\prod_{x : A} f_1 x = f_2 x$. It's a standard trick. Or are you after something else?

Comment: This is what I am after.  I definitely want to weaken $f_1 = f_2$ to just being a homotopy.  But if I do that, Agda complains about lots of unresolved metas.  Basically I need to weaken both $f$ and $g$ (inverse of $f$) for the metas to resolve.  I was hoping there was a 'deep' reason for this.

Comment: Actually, I guess what I really need is to unravel (2.4.11) completely, as I don't want just the first component to be a homotopy, but the inverses as well.

Comment: You should also specify that the homotopy between $f_1$ and $f_2$ takes $\mathsf{isequiv}(f_1)$ to $\mathsf{isequiv}(f_1)$, whatever that means.

Comment: I wonder if my last comment makes any sense. If $f_1$ is an equivalence and is homotopic to $f_2$ then surely $f_2$ is an equivalence.

Comment: I am not sure what Agda's problem is, but I think it's a problem with Agda or with your use of it; as Andrej said, you shouldn't need to even mention the inverse in defining what it means for two equivalences to be equal.

Comment: @MikeShulman: I believe that the problem is with the definition of "equivalence of equivalences" that I was using, not Agda.  Thus the reason for this question.  So if 'isequiv' (rather than isprop) is indeed a proposition, then I ought to be able to use that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are homotopic as my definition.  What is surprising is that this does not have the "shape" of an equivalence.

Comment: I do not undestand your comment about "shape".

Comment: @AndrejBauer: my imprecision there.  I mentally chose a definition of equivalence (say $\texttt{biinv}$) and took it as they "shape" that an equivalence must have.  In particular, as things get weakened, I don't believe that a weakened version of $\texttt{biinv}$ will actually be a mere proposition.  So equivalence-of-equivalence is more than just a single homotopy - I think.  That is what this whole question is trying to ascertain!

Comment: It's true that "isequiv" is not necessarily a mere proposition without function extensionality, if that's what you mean.  But I don't think there will be any definition of equivalence that will be a mere proposition without function extensionality.  What you should do if you don't have funext is use a definition that makes sense and is practical without funext and reduces to a "correct" one if you do have funext.